# Linux huge page value in sysctl.conf

Tags: linux

Why do we configue huge page value in Linux ?

When we will configure huge page value and how we calculate the huge page value ?

Answer (score 0):

Usually the huge page value is configured, when large  memory pages needs to be allocated contigously (in a sequence) in RAM.

The below link has an example, which explains when and how:

https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/5/html/Tuning_and_Optimizing_Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux_for_Oracle_9i_and_10g_Databases/sect-Oracle_9i_and_10g_Tuning_Guide-Large_Memory_Optimization_Big_Pages_and_Huge_Pages-Sizing_Big_Pages_and_Huge_Pages.html

**When you need Huge page value:**

When the applications require large blocks of memory for processing.

**Translation lookaside buffer (TLB)** is a  chaching mechaninsm for memory, which is used for quicker memory access. During memory management mapping entries are entered in to **TLB**, so that it helps in quick access of memory whenever required. (To know much about **TLB** refer https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_lookaside_buffer)

**TLB** has a fixed number of slots, So it is a scarce source. So when the application has requirement for large blocks of memory,using huge pages will have less number of entries in the **TLB**, so that the **TLB** is used much effectively.

If you want more in depth information on **huge page** and **TLB**, Please walk through below Kernel documentation. But it is too deep.

https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/vm/hugetlbpage.txt

Comment: Can you please explain me when we configure the huge page value

Comment: Updated the answer please look into it